# JavaScript: Fullcalendar - Insert Break / Empty Row Between Months

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-api) to render a calendar.

Everything is working fine, but I have a specific request that I've been trying to solve, which is: show two months, but have some kind of visual separation (i.e. empty row) between them.

I have my custom view set-up, but have no idea where to even begin on inserting a row between months. (My initial thoughts are: it's probably easier to insert a 'row' into the calendar  after it renders, as opposed to getting too deep).

I was thinking about looping through the calendar's HTML on the `fc-day-top` CSS class and use Moment.js to match the date and then break the row by inserting html into the DOM; but I'm not sure if that's the right approach. (please see the code below and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjr73m41/))

I am able to select the last day of the respective month, but am now trying to figure out the best way to insert HTML into the table with correct offsets before and after the split.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('my-calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid','timeGrid', 'list' ],

        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listDay,dayGridMonth,monthView2'
        },
        views: {
            monthView2: {
                type: 'dayGrid',
                duration: { 
                    months: 2 
                },
                buttonText: '2-Month View',
                showNonCurrentDates: false,
            },
            dayGridMonth: { 
                buttonText: 'Month View',
                showNonCurrentDates: false,
            },
            listDay: { buttonText: 'Day List' },
        },
        defaultView: 'monthView2',
        //  With the code below: my initial though is: find the last day of the month, and insert <td>s and a row to split it
                  datesRender: function( info ){
                    $('.fc-row.fc-week').each(function() { 
                      var thisWeek =  $(this);
                      var $d_i = 0;
                      var  htmlCellStringBefore = htmlCellStringAfter = '';
                      $(thisWeek).find('.fc-day-top').each(function() {
                          $d_i++;
                          var thisDay = $(this).data('date');
                          var thisDateYear = moment(thisDay).year();
                          var thisDateMonth = moment(thisDay).month();
                          var lastDay = new Date(thisDateYear, thisDateMonth + 1, 0);
                          var lastDayMoment = moment(lastDay).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                          // Match the last day, if matches, cut the table and insert HTML
                          if(thisDay == lastDayMoment){
                            var cellIteratorBefore = 7 - $d_i;
                            var cellIteratorAfter = 7 - cellIteratorBefore;
                            // Looping to create number of offset cells before break for insertion
                              for (i = 0; i < cellIteratorBefore; i++) { 
                                htmlCellStringBefore += '<td class="cellBefore"></td>';
                              }
                              // Looping to create number of offset cells after break for insertion
                              for (i = 0; i < cellIteratorAfter; i++) { 
                                htmlCellStringAfter+= '<td class="cellAfter"></td>';
                              }
                              var returnHtmlHead = htmlCellStringBefore + '</tr></thead>'; // inserting empty cells after date to break into head
                              var returnHtmlBody = htmlCellStringBefore + '</tr></tbody></table>'; // inserting empty cells after date to break into table body
                              var thisTableFcBG = $(thisWeek).find('.fc-bg tbody td');
                              var thisTableFcSkeleton = $(thisWeek).find('.fc-content-skeleton tbody td');
                              var thisTableFcBGNthTableCell = $(thisTableFcBG)[cellIteratorBefore];
                              var thisTableFcSkeletonNthTableCell = $(thisTableFcSkeleton)[cellIteratorBefore];
                              var MonthName = moment(lastDayMoment).add(1, 'days').format("MMMM");
                              $('<div class="break-month-title">'+ MonthName+ '</div>').insertAfter(thisWeek);
                              // This part is messy and i'm trying figure out the best way to split up the tables
                              $(returnHtmlHead).insertAfter(thisDay);
                              $(returnHtmlBody + '<div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content"><div class="break-month">BREAK MONTH</div><div class="fc-bg"><table><thead><tr>'+ htmlCellStringAfter).insertAfter(thisTableFcBGNthTableCell);
                             $(returnHtmlBody + '<div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr>' + htmlCellStringAfter).insertAfter(thisTableFcSkeletonNthTableCell); 
                          }
                      });
                  });
                }
    });

    calendar.render();
```

```css
.break-month {
  background:#f10000;
}

.break-month-title {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3rem;
    font-size:2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="my-calendar"></div>
```

I also have a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjr73m41/

Comment: @mplungjan the docs for the lib literally say to post on SO: "If you still can’t find an answer, post your question on the StackOverflow fullcalendar tag. When entering a new question, make sure you tag it with fullcalendar."

Comment: Ok let’s hope he’ll pass by ;)

Comment: Ryan - It'd be helpful if you setup a runnable example of your code rather than expecting us to set it up for you to debug your problem. Maybe add a jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: @imjared Clicking the `[<>]` here will start a stacksnippet editor that in this case does a great job too

Comment: You can't do what you want via the settings. To create this kind of unusual setup you'd need to create a whole new view type by [creating a custom view from a new class](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js). But even if you do it by forking an existing class from the source, it won't be a simple task to create or indeed to maintain it to be compatible with future releases of fullCalendar. Before you go down this route I'd suggest you consider carefully whether this 2-month view requirement is truly essential or just a luxury - can you deliver the same info using standard features?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, I'll work to put together a fiddle. Apologies if it wasn't clear in my initial post.

Comment: I've updated the initial thread with a fiddle and my initial thoughts on using `datesRender` to loop through the calendar, not sure if this is on the right track or not and thoughts welcome :).